# Svelte (Vite) + Bootstrap 5 + SvelteStrap error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ButtonColor'

Tags: typescript, svelte, bootstrap-5

I'm using Svelte (Vite) + Bootstrap 5 + SvelteStrap. My code is the following:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<script>
    import { Button } from 'sveltestrap';
    let color = "danger";
</script>

<div>
    <Button color="{color}">{color}</Button>
</div>
```

This works normally on the browser, but VSCode says:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ButtonColor'.

I'm just starting out with Svelte, and I'm trying to modify the standard example on the SvelteStrap website:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<script lang="ts">
  import { Button } from 'sveltestrap';
  const colors: any = [
    'primary',
    'secondary',
    'success',
    'danger',
    'warning',
    'info',
    'light',
    'dark'
  ];
</script>

{#each colors as color}
  <div>
    <Button {color}>{color}</Button>
  </div>
{/each}
```

Using the standard example, no erros are fired. What am I doing wrong? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typing issue, the error is generated by TypeScript.

The expected type of the `color` property is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of various string values, but by default an array of string literals will be typed as just `string[]`, so its items will no longer be assignable to a more specific string-literal-based type.

You should be able to use `as const` here to restrict the type of the array to be literal-based:

```js
const colors = [
    'primary',
    'secondary',
    'success',
    'danger',
    'warning',
    'info',
    'light',
    'dark'
] as const; // <--
```

---

This is the full [`ButtonColor` type definition](https://unpkg.com/browse/sveltestrap@5.9.0/src/Button.d.ts):

```js
declare type ButtonColor =
  | 'primary'
  | 'secondary'
  | 'success'
  | 'danger'
  | 'warning'
  | 'info'
  | 'light'
  | 'dark'
  | 'link';
```

The type is not exported (though it should be), so it cannot be used directly, but you can extract it from the `Button` class:

```js
import type { SvelteComponentTyped } from 'svelte';
import type { Button } from 'sveltestrap';

type PropsOf<C> = C extends SvelteComponentTyped<infer Props> ? Props : never;
type ButtonProps = PropsOf<Button>;
type ButtonColor = Exclude<ButtonProps['color'], undefined>;
```

[TS Playground Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAygNxQGxhQGEJwIA7FCmAFWRQBM4BfOAMyjLgHIBnPIRQ8A3AChQkWAgYY4AIQCuMGJVYcuIXgIJE%20MKAEMwosWKSo4ABS5g%20AeXYAeYgD44AXjjE4KAB5EFIx82IJEpORUNPSojE7AFOwoUNa2fO4A-KkQdnAAXHBUeFDiFmhKKpQ2OSFe1XaOThWqFK6lss2UpPjQnnAAon4AxviKjChNyi31fADaPEMQPVA8ALoANHCKQSjsCUxtYgD0R3BnAHoZQA)

You could also type your array using this:

```js
const colors: ButtonColor[] = [
    'primary',
    'secondary',
    'success',
    'danger',
    'warning',
    'info',
    'light',
    'dark'
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-detail explanation, it solved my issue!